# Can we take out an integrand random variable which does not depend on time from the stochastic integral?

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $Y$ is a ${\mathbb R}$-valued random variable, $(X_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ is one-dimensional stochastic process and $(W_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ is a one-dimensional Brownian motion.
Then is the following formula correct?
$$
Y \int_{0}^{t}X_{s}{\rm d}W_{s}=\int_{0}^{t}YX_{s}{\rm d}W_{s}, \quad t \geq 0.
$$
Here, these integrands $(X_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ and $(YX_{t})_{t \geq 0}$ have some conditions that allow the stochastic integrals to be defined.

Comment: Does $Y$ depend on $X$ or $W$?

Comment: This statement is explained in detail on page 148 of the following book: I. Karatzas and S. E. Shreve. Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus, 2nd ed. Springer-Verlag New York, Inc. (1998).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, because in terms of an outcome $\omega$,
$\begin{eqnarray*}
&&Y(\omega) \int_{0}^{t}X_{s}(\omega){\rm d}W_{s}(\omega)\\
&=&
Y(\omega)
\lim_n\sum_{k=0}^{tn}
X_{k/n}(\omega)(W_{k/n+\Delta}-W_{k/n})(\omega)\\
&=&
\lim_n\sum_{k=0}^{tn}
Y(\omega)X_{k/n}(\omega)(W_{k/n+\Delta}-W_{k/n})(\omega)\\
&=&
\int_{0}^{t}Y(\omega)X_{s}(\omega){\rm d}W_{s}(\omega)
\end{eqnarray*}
$